# Efficient way to store multiple ranges of numbers for future searching

Tags: java, algorithm, performance

I have a text file full of IP addresses ranges. I use `ip2long` to convert the addresses to longs so that I have an easy way to check if a given address is within the range. However, I'm looking for an efficient way to store these ranges and then search to see if an IP address exists within any of the ranges.

The current method I'm thinking of is to create an object that has the low end and the high end of a range with a function to check if the value is within range. I would store these objects in a list and check each one. However, I feel this might be a bit inefficient and can get slow as the list increases.

Is there a better way than what I'm thinking?

Comment: You could certainly use a Guava RangeSet...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the following data structures may help you:

**Segment Tree**

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree) ([Implementation](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/99misc/SegmentTree.java.html)):

> Is a tree data structure for storing intervals, or segments. It allows querying which of the stored segments contain a given point.

---

**Interval Tree**

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) ([Implementation](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/93intersection/IntervalST.java.html)):

> Is a tree data structure to hold intervals. Specifically, it allows one to efficiently find all intervals that overlap with any given interval or point.

---

**Range Tree**

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_tree) ([Implementation](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/92search/RangeTree.java.html)):

> Is an ordered tree data structure to hold a list of points. It allows all points within a given range to be reported efficiently.

Answer (score 3):

Assume the ranges do not overlap, otherwise you could combine them into one range.

Then create an array of increasingly ordered `begin1, end1, begin2, end2, ...`.
Where `begini` is inclusive in the range, and `endi` is just after the range.

Now do a binary search and:

```
int pos = ... .binarySearch ...
boolean found = pos >= 0;
if (!found) {
    pos = ~pos;
}
boolean atBegin = pos % 2 == 0;
boolean insideRange = (found && atBegin) || (!found && !atBegin);
//Equivalent: boolean insideRange = found == atBegin;
```

The lookup test is `O(log N)`. The creation of the initial array is much more complex.

Java binarySearch delivers the index when found, and ~index (ones complement, < 0) when not found.

---

Addendum: I think the above can be "smartly" comprised by

```
boolean insideRange = (Arrays.binarySearch(...) & 1) == 0;
```

though an explaining comment would definitely be needed. I leave that to the reader.

Comment: It's almost certainly not O(log N). You say order the ranges, which means at least O(N log N) if they aren't perfectly sorted in his text file. Moreover, even scanning over each range to make the array is O(N). I know binary search is O(log N), but saying it like that is (in my opinion) misleading, as it seems you are talking about your solution being O(log N). Otherwise, pretty good solution.

Comment: @nhouser9 I meant about the retrieval, considering the array of IPs built just once in advance. But a good remark.

Comment: @nhouser9 I think Joop Eggen meant lookup

Comment: Of course he meant lookup (I even say that I know that's what he means in my comment). But I think it is misleading to tell someone "This is O(log N)" when answering their question if your solution isn't actually O(log N). Who cares if the fastest part of the algorithm is O(log N) anyway? Anyone who cares about time complexity cares about the slowest part of the algorithm. At best, the line "This is O(log N)" is irrelevant - at worst it is very misleading.

Comment: I cannot guarantee the ranges won't overlap. I do not manage the list so anything is possible. Also, the ranges are not in order, so I would have to sort as well.

Comment: Do the ranges need to be updated often w.r.t. lookups? Does one need to remove ranges? Then tree like structures are indeed better. Only when ranges are much less often updated my solution is fine. Merging overlapping ranges is easy, though removing an old range then cannot be done.